# Null color during start up

Tags: java, class, colors, enums, fixed

So I am just having some fun when I realize that the color is returning null. The odd thing though, is the Color is made during the implementation. The code I have is this:

```
package org.legend.game;

import java.awt.Color;

public class Type {

    final static Type GROUND;
    final static Type AIR;

    static{
        AIR = new Type(0);
        GROUND = new Type(1);
    }

    private Color c;

    Type(int type) {
        Color c = colorFromType(type);
        System.out.println(c);
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return c;
    }

    private Color colorFromType(int num) {
        switch (num) {
        case 0:
            return new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
        default:
            return new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using enums before, but that did not work either. Technically speaking, this should work, but for some reason, the colors always return null.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I am running this through an Applet FYI.

Example print:

```
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
//Classic NullPointerException linking to the Type#getColor() method.
```

Thanks,

Legend.

Comment: Might I recommend just doing: "AIR = new Type(0,new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a `NullPointerException` when you do

```
type.getColor()
```

then it's `type` that is `null`, not the return value of the method call.

---

Once you sorted out the error, I suggest you go back to an enum. That's a much better approach for these types of objects.

Comment: Depends on your code. You haven't made the constructor private, so I can't tell.

Comment: And in which file / line do you get the NPE?!

Comment: You probably haven't initialized your `tiles` properly. I bet some `tiles[i]` is null. Here's what you do: Right above the `variable.getColor()` call which produces the NPE, you do `System.out.println(variable);` and check the content of the variable.

Comment: There's to much code for me to dig through. Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and I'll look into it.

Comment: Found the error. Silly mistake, forgot to declare the Type t in Tile when initializing.